# Does terraform support map of list?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops

I want to create a variable that will resemble the following yaml format

```
Dev:
 - name: Michael
   type: Senior
 - name: Ron
   type: Junior
 - name: Lex
   type: Senior
 - name: Rocky
   type: Junior
Test:
 - name: Rony
   type: Junior
 - name: Ryan
   type: Junior
 - name: John
   type: Senior
 - name: Brad
   type: Junior
```

What is the best way in Terraform to represent the above data structure?.

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/types.html

Answer (score 1):

If you require that each of the list elements will have exactly those keys `name` and `type`, but that the top-level keys are arbitrary, then the most direct [type constraint](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/type-constraints.html) that would accept that data structure would be:

```
  type = map(list(object({
    name = string
    type = string
  }))
```

I've assumed here that the order of list items is significant. If instead this is just a collection of distinct objects in no particular order (for example, if you intend to use each one to declare an entirely-separate object) then it might make more sense to use the `set(...)` type kind instead of the `list(...)` type kind, to make it clearer that the ordering isn't important and that each item must be unique.